# Commenting configuration changes

Tags: administration, process-builder, approval-process, flow, documentation

When I have to do "strange" things in code, I comment it.

Salesforce has introduced many places for declarative business logic (e.g., Process Builder, Flows).  Is there any way to add comments near the business logic in these or other declarative tools, or must we create a separate document(s)?

Comment: I use description field to do the commenting. It also helpful to tell what this component is all about to the Admin/Developer who going to support/develop down the years for my org

Comment: Try commenting  Lead assignment rules :-)

Answer (score 1):

The only real options are using the Description fields on the flows and the Flow Elements or on Process Builder the Description of the process itself. This is probably the closest equivalent to using comment lines in code and the the other element is using descriptive names for the Process Steps or Flow Elements.

Using Steps in a Flow will prevent it from being activated so can only be used during the build phase.

[image: Flow Description]

[image: Process Builder Description]

Answer (score 0):

There is something called "Step" in Draft Tools of Flows.  I use that to place my comments.  Try, it is useful.

[image]